# im trying to make a speed art video in premiere pro cc 2018 but after speeding up the footage it keeps being laggy

Tags: premiere

im trying to make a speed art video in premiere pro cc 2018
the original video is almost 2 hours long and i speed it up by 6000% to get it down to the time i want the video to be

but after speeding it up it only shows like every 10 frame or something which makes it really laggy to look at
it lags in premiere but it also still lags after rendering/exporting it

ive tried alot of different settings before and while exporting

but i cant seem to find anything onlne that solves my prolem tried alot of what i could find online but either it just get exportet as an unplayable file or it get exported really laggy

Comment: Did you try to check the exported video on a different PC/operative system?